# Object wont rotate from its last position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have an object, and it rotates just fine. However, this is a click and drag rotation. Whenever I rotate it to one position, it stays there, but when I try to rotate it again, it rotates from the starting point, instead of where it left off from. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Basket_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{
     private float baseAngle = 0.0f;

     void OnMouseDown() 
     {
         Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
         pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
         baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
         baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
     }

     void OnMouseDrag()
     {
         Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
         pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
         float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.down);
     }
}
```

I'm a bit of a noob, I kinda copied this code off of some guy and modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you always set `transform.rotation` value completely ignoring its initial value before rotation starts, so it rotates each time from same starting point. Simple solution is to save the value on mouse down, and apply it to overall rotation on mouse drag, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Basket_Script : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float baseAngle = 0.0f;
    private Quaternion startRotation = Quaternion.identity;

    void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
        baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        // Remember the value
        startRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
        // Multiply desired rotation by starting rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.down) * startRotation;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.